# Promise is not assignable to React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, promise

From `MoviesPage.tsx` I'm calling a function of `movies.service.tsx` to fetch data of a movie (result is a promise that contains an object, data is fetched correctly since I can console it out).

However, I cannot assign the result to a state, I'm getting a message "Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'."

How can I solve it?
Thanks!

MoviesPage.tsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { fetchMovie } from "../../services/movies.service";
import {Grid, Card, CardMedia} from '@material-ui/core';
import noImage from '../../images/no-image-available.png';

interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  vote_average: number;
  overview: string;
  poster_path?: string;
  date: string;
}

const MoviePage = (props: any) => {

  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>(
    {
      id: 0,
      title: '',
      vote_average: 0,
      overview: '',
      poster_path: noImage,
      date: '', 
    }
  );

const currentMovieId = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];

useEffect(() => {

  const fetchedMovieInfo = fetchMovie(Number(currentMovieId));
  console.log(fetchedMovieInfo);
  // HERE I GET AN ERROR MESSAGE
  setMovie(fetchedMovieInfo);

}, [currentMovieId]);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Card className="card">
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt={"Poster of " + movie.title}
              className="BeerListItem-img"
              image={posterBaseUrl + movie.poster_path}
              title={movie.title}
            />
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default MoviePage;
```

movies.service.tsx

```
const movieApiBaseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";


 export async function fetchMovie (currentMovieId: number ) {
  return await fetch(
    `${movieApiBaseUrl}/movie/${currentMovieId}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((body) => {
      console.log(body);
      return body;
  })
    .catch(() => {
        return {};
    });
}
```

Comment: fetchMovie is an async function, and they _always_ return promises, so fetchedMovieInfo is indeed a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `async/await` in the `useEffect` to get real data:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const callAPI = async () => {
    const fetchedMovieInfo = await fetchMovie(Number(currentMovieId));
    console.log(fetchedMovieInfo);
    setMovie(fetchedMovieInfo);
  }
  
  callAPI()
}, [currentMovieId]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't waiting for the promise to resolve, this can by done via async await as answered by @Viet, or by `then` i.e.

```
useEffect(() => {

  const fetchedMovieInfo = fetchMovie(Number(currentMovieId)).then((fetchedMovieInfo) => {
    console.log(fetchedMovieInfo); // this is now resolved
    setMovie(fetchedMovieInfo);
  }).catch(error => setErrorState(error)) // handle error case

}, [currentMovieId]);
```

One gotcha when you are using `useEffect` is that you can't define an async function handler directly. This wouldn't work...

```
useEffect(async () => { ...
```

You can read up on why but basically useEffect should only return a function to perform any cleanup required. Defining an inline async function like this would instead return it a promise, so you'll often see `.then` used inside a `useEffect` call

Comment: Got it Tim, many thanks for your answer! I'll investigate about how promises and useEffect() work